# how to count the exact number of words in a string that has empty spaces between words?

Tags: java

Write a method called wordCount that accepts a String as its parameter and returns the number of words in the String. A word is a sequence of one or more nonspace characters (any character other than ' '). For example, the call wordCount("hello") should return 1, the call wordCount("how are you?") should return 3, the call wordCount(" this string has wide spaces ") should return 5, and the call wordCount(" ") should return 0.

I made a function:

```
public static int wordCount(String s){

  int counter = 0;

  for(int i=0; i<=s.length()-1; i++) {

    if(Character.isLetter(s.charAt(i))){

      counter++;

      for(i<=s.length()-1; i++){

        if(s.charAt(i)==' '){

          counter++;
        }
      }                
    }
  }

  return counter;
}
```

But i know this has 1 limitation that it will also count the number of spaces after all the words in the string have finished nad it will also count 2 blank spaces as possibly being 2 words :(
Is there a predefined function for word count? or can this code be corrected?

Comment: Can't you just do `String#split("\\s");` and get length of resulting array.

Comment: Are you missing the `[homework]` tag?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

If you want to ignore leading, trailing and duplicate spaces you can use

```
String trimmed = text.trim();
int words = trimmed.isEmpty() ? 0 : trimmed.split("\\s+").length;
```

Comment: +1 for the first answer taking into account multiple spaces in a row.

Comment: And leading spaces.  split() will ignore trailing delimiters by default.

Comment: @PeterLawrey- fails for text=" ";

Comment: What do you mean fails?  Do you mean it returns 1?

Comment: @PeterLawrey-yA it returns 1, it should have returned 0

Comment: @IamAPseudo-Intellectual I have updated it to handle empty or blank strings.

Answer (score 6):

```
public static int wordCount(String s){
    if (s == null)
       return 0;
    return s.trim().split("\\s+").length;
}
```

Have fun with the function.

Answer (score 2):

```
String str="I am a good boy";
String[] words=str.split("\\s+");
System.out.println(words.length);
```

Comment: Fails for " this string has wide spaces "

Answer (score 1):

Simply use `s.split(" ").length` and for wide spaces...use `s.trim().replaceAll("\\s+"," ").split(" ").length`

Comment: Fails for " this string has wide spaces "

Comment: This would work in case of multiple whitespaces s.replaceAll("\\s+"," ").split(" ").length

Answer (score 1):

```
public static int wordCount(String s){
    int counter=0;
    for(int i=0;i<=s.length()-1;i++){
        if(Character.isLetter(s.charAt(i))){
            counter++;
            for(;i<=s.length()-1;i++){
                if(s.charAt(i)==' '){
                    i++;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return counter;
}
```

This is what you need if don't use the predefined function. I have tested it by myself. Please let me know if there is any bugs!

Answer (score 0):

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)

> Splits this string around matches of the given regular expression.

Comment: I would use the Java 7 javadoc. ;)

Answer (score 0):

It should be easy with:

```
String[] arr = "how are you sir".split("\\s");
System.out.printf("Count [%d]%n", arr.length);
```

Answer (score 0):

Added some lines to your code:

```
public static int wordCount(String s){
    int counter=0;
    for(int i=0;i<=s.length()-1;i++){
            if(Character.isLetter(s.charAt(i))){
                    counter++;
                    for(;i<=s.length()-1;i++){
                            if(s.charAt(i)==' '){
                                    counter++;
                                    i++;
                                    while (s.charAt(i)==' ')
                                        i++;
                                    }
                            }

                    }


            }
            return counter;
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

My few solutions:

```
public static int wordcount1(String word) {

        if (word == null || word.trim().length() == 0) {
            return 0;
        }

        int counter = 1;

        for (char c : word.trim().toCharArray()) {
            if (c == ' ') {
                counter++;
            }
        }
        return counter;
    }
```

//

```
public static int wordcount2(String word) {
        if (word != null || word.length() > 0) {
            return word.trim().length()
                    - word.trim().replaceAll("[ ]", "").length() + 1;
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    }
```

// Recursive

```
public static int wordcount3(String word) {
        if (word == null || word.length() == 0) {
            return 0;
        }
        if (word.charAt(0) == ' ') {
            return 1 + wordcount3(word.substring(1));
        }
        return wordcount3(word.substring(1));
    }
```

//

```
public static int wordcount4(String word) {
        if (word == null || word.length() == 0) {
            return 0;
        }

        String check = word.trim();
        int counter = 1;
        for (int i = 0; i < check.length(); i++) {
            if (i > 0 && Character.isSpaceChar(check.charAt(i))
                    && !Character.isSpaceChar(check.charAt(i - 1))) {
                counter++;
            }
        }
        return counter;
    }
```

Comment: Solution will fail if there are more than 1 consecutive spaces in between words.