# How to count how many characters are in each word in a String in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, string, count

I've looked all over for an answer for my question, but all of the questions are either about how many words are in each String or aren't what I'm looking for.

So far I've read in a file using Scanner and I separated it into 3 strings using newline as the delimiter and put them into an array.

What I want to do is to count how many words are in each String and then have the output be something similar to `String 1 contains  3 two-letter words, 4  three-letter words, 6 five-letter words`.

I honestly just have no idea how to do it. I'm not asking for you to write the code for me, just how to go about it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This post will be helpful, doesn't solve all of your problems but solves part of it. http://stackoverflow.com/q/8924599/4808407

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start with one of the solutions you found for counting the number of words in a string (that actually identifies the words).  Define an array of integers, and use it to keep track of how many words of a given length you can seen so far.  Modify the word counter to increment the appropriate counter for a given word's length where it increments the overall count of words.

Comment: Thank you for this! Got my code working.