# Simple java program that finds the number of words in a sentence

Tags: java

```
  public static String number(String words) {
      int length = words.length;
      int total = 0;
      while(int index < length) {
          total = total + 1;
          index = index + 1;
          }
      }
      String output;
      output = total + " word";
      return output;
  }
```

Example output for this would be:

```
numberOfWords("Hello whats up?")
3 word
```

This would work for all proper sentences but I have to account for bad input for example:

```
"Hi             my         name      is bob"
```

, this would be like thirty plus words. Also

```
"                 "
```

, should be 0 words. Is there any simple way to make the first example to "hi my name is bob" ?

Comment: Wait, your method is named `numberOfWords` and it returns a `String`?

Comment: Its the matter of the exercise rather than me naming it

Comment: Is it, now? The string returned only returns the number of words in the input with `" words"` appended. Given that adding this constant string is not part of the logic, why embed it in the method at all?

Comment: Details: Given a string, return the number of words
contained in the string. Also says inputs: String words, outputs: String output. Is that not what it currently is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can do something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8924599/how-to-count-the-exact-number-of-words-in-a-string-that-has-empty-spaces-between) :

```
String trimmed = text.trim();
int words = trimmed.isEmpty() ? 0 : trimmed.split("\\s+").length;
```

or (simplest way):

```
use str.replaceAll("\\s+"," ");
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplest will work in every case

```
        String word = "Hi             my         name      is bob";
        word = word.replaceAll("\\s+", " ");
        String count [] = word.split(" ");

        System.out.println(count.length);
```